# Find and Replace text in the entire table using a MySQL query

Tags: hacked

Website has been hacked and they have injected javascript into every single post, page and product (woocommerce) - Editing every page manually would take for ever, we have over 3000 posts.

Is there a simple find and replace we could use to remove this javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have SSH access? [WP-CLI via `search-replace`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/).

```
$ wp search-replace '<script>bad javascript code</script>' '' --precise
```

By default, this only searches for tables registered in `$wpdb`. To overwrite this behaviour, you can use either the `--all-tables` or `--all-tables-with-prefix` flag. (Or pass table names to the command manually.)

**Alternative**: Easiest would be to download a dump, search/replace in that file and finally import again.

1. Download complete db backup
2. search & replace with your favourite text editor, replacing `<script>bad javascript code</script>` through an empty string
3. Delete tables
4. Upload your edited backup

Comment: Yes, I think that would be the quickest, although DB pretty large so could cause problems when trying to open it. Will give it a shot. Thank you.

Comment: Depending on your OS, [there are solutions for this](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=search%20replace%20in%20large%20text%20file)

Comment: Not that `wp search-replace` only searches in tables registered to the `$wpdb` object. If a plugin creates a table that isn't registered there, it won't get searched.